# Billing address not being saved to quote

Tags: onepage-checkout, javascript, billing-address

I have a problem with Onepage checkout not saving customer billing address to the quote.

When I add a new address then refresh the page the address is removed. If I `var_dump` the current `checkout/session` I get a completely different address from the one I just entered.

Also, if I try to resubmit the same address from the same billing address form I get an error in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'collectSummaryDataForm' of undefined
```

Which is this line:

```
checkout.collectSummaryDataForm('billing');
```

Has anyone had issues with customer billing address not being saved to quote could offer some insight on how to resolve please?

Answer (score 3):

You need to check below code in your checkout template file i.e billing.phtml
 getAddress()->getId() ?>" id="billing:address_id" />

Then checked the saveBilling method in your onepage checkout controller for 
$customerAddressId = $this->getRequest()->getPost('billing_address_id', false);

make false to true and check.

Remeber you need to override the controller for this method.
Do not modify core controller.